# Spring-Security remove application context in redirect

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am building an application using Spring-Boot (1.2.2) using the Spring-Boot Spring-Security dependency(which comes with 3.2.6).

I have deployed my application to Tomcat as "site" context, but I have apache in front of it stripping out the "site" part of the URL (by which I mean, the public facing URL does not include the "site" element, but apache adds that in before passing through to tomcat - so stripping is probably the wrong word :).

I want to force my application to be HTTP only, so have set up the config to force that:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class AccountSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {      

    @Override protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {              
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll()
        http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresInsecure()

    }
```

If I then visit the application on HTTPS `https://example.com/homepage`, Spring redirects it, but adds the "site" element back in - so now gets re-directed to `http://example.com/site/homepage` - which 404s.

Is there anyway to configure this redirect so it doesn't add site everytime?

Comment: Probably an apache configuration issue. What does the "strip" configuration look like?

Comment: Thanks @holmis83 - I have used the wrong word I think, Apache is actually adding "site" into the request before passing to tomcat/Spring so it correctly matches the applications context in tomcat.  The apache config is just doing a ProxyPassMatch with some simple regex to pass the URL plus the "site" part on